# insertion in middle of a linked list in php

Tags: php, list, linked-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Insert at particular index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793670/php-insert-at-particular-index)

Is it possible to to insert in the middle of a linked list in php. If yes, can someone please provide me with the code of the function that implements it?

Comment: What does your current LinkedList look like?

Comment: Are you using SPL linked lists? Or have you written some kind of home-brew code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

```
function insertIntoMiddle($LinkedList, $NewItem)
{
    // we will use current as a pointer to the current position in our list
    // if we arrive at the middle, we insert the $NewItem
    $currentIndex = 0;
    $currentItem = $LinkedList->getFirstItem();

    // calculate the middle of your list
    $middleIndex = floor($LinkedList->getLength() / 2);

    // Loop over the list until you get the item in the middle
    while (++$currentIndex < $middleIndex)
    {
        $currentItem = $currentItem->getNextItem();
    }

    // insert the $NewItem between $currentItem and the next
    $NewItem->setNextItem($currentItem->getNextItem());
    $currentItem->setNextItem($NewItem);

    // also setPreviousItem() if you have linked your list both ways
}
```

This is of course pseudo-code as you didn't provide any example code.